# How to pass an array to another class

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a programme for a Quiz score, I have the array in the main method and I need to supply an appropriate constructor and methods in a separate class, “addQuizScore(int score)”, “getTotalScore”. I'm still new to Java and stuck on how to do this correctly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentQuiz 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int [] score = {7,8,5,6,0,10,7,6}; 

        StudentQuizInfo newStudent = new StudentQuizInfo(score);

        System.out.println("total score: " +newStudent.getTotalScore());

    }
}


import java.util.*;
public class StudentQuizInfo {

    private int overallScore = 0;
    private int totalScore = 0;


    public StudentQuizInfo(int[] score) {
    }

    public int addQuizScore(int [] score)
    {
        int k; 
        int overallScore = 0; 
        for(k = 0; k <score.length; k++) 
        { 
            overallScore = overallScore + score[k]; 
            } 
        return overallScore;
        }

    int getTotalScore()
    {
        int totalScore = overallScore;
        return totalScore;
        }
    }
```

ATM the code prints `totalscore: 0` which is incorrect.

I realise my current code is very poor, so any pointers to how i can correct this would be much appreciated, particularly on how to use addQuizScore correctly.
Thanks

Comment: Why not put `addQuizScore(score)` in the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
newStudent.addQuizScore(score);
```

after

```
StudentQuizInfo newStudent = new StudentQuizInfo(score);
```

should fix the problem.

Additionally, your architecture is a bit odd. Your constructor is doing nothing the way it is written now. As you have a method called `addQuizScore` I assume, that you don't need to keep the score inside of the `StudentQuizInfo` object, so you can safely remove the `int[] score` parameter from the constructor of the class.

Also the variables `overallCore` and `totalScore` seem to be redundant.

Comment: I dont think that is the proper way. either remove the parameter score from constructor or use addQuizScore method. Dont keep both.

Comment: i don't think so, since the class variable `overallScore` is not touched in that method. 
But adding `this.overallScore = overallScore` befor `return overallScore` in addition to your solution should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor like this

```
public StudentQuizInfo(int[] score) {
    addQuizScore(score)
}
```

or

```
StudentQuizInfo newStudent = new StudentQuizInfo(score);
newStudent.addQuizScore(score);
```

Comment: In your latter code, why bother passing `score` to the constructor?